# Use both b-tree and BRIN indexes in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning

I have rather large tables (> 1000 M rows) where I have to do quick lookups. They are typically indexed with composite indexes to enable index-only scans like this `CREATE INDEX table (study, analysis, gene, sample) INCLUDE (value)` where a study can contain several analyses, which contain many genes, each of which contains measurements for some samples. One type of query would be to get the value for a given gene in all samples in an analysis. This would return ~500 rows. Another type of query would return values for all genes and samples in an analysis. This would return millions of rows. I wonder if it would make sense to also include a BRIN index on `study, analysis` to speed up such queries. It would then be redundant with the existing b-tree index. Is this bad practice that just adds overhead and complexity, or do you think it will be used by the scheduler like I want?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the results will typically not be cached, so it would have to read from disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index on `(study, analysis, gene, sample) INCLUDE (value)` would still be usable for a query like `select gene, sample, value from t where study='PNAS908' and analysis = 'the correct one'`.  And will probably be better than BRIN, or at last not worse by enough to matter.

Note that if "analysis" is just labelled in a low-entropy way within a study (a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, log, linear, sqrt, intervention, SOC, placebo, ...), such that the same analysis identifier is reused from study to study, then the multi-column BRIN index is unlikely to do what you want.  The columns in a BRIN index are not hierarchical like they are within a btree index, they are each independent.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't get the scheduler to favor the BRIN instead of the b-tree index even when selecting very many rows, so I'll guess I just drop the idea. "analysis" is a foreign key that's unique to each study, so the issue you mention wouldn't be a problem here. Good to know though!